# How to show or hide radio button based on the condition

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

First of all sorry for the bad English.

I have four radio buttons and i need to show or hide the radio buttons based on the condition.

Here is my sample code.

```
if(condition 1 ==true)
{
    div1.visible=true;
    div2.visible=true;
    div3.visible=true;
}
else if(condition 2 ==true)
{
     div1.visible=true;
     div2.visible=true;
     div3.visible=false;
}
else if(condition 3 ==true)
{
     div4.visible=true;
 }
```

Now I am using separate div tags for every radio button it's working fine if I use separate div tags. But my task is not to use the div tags, I tried by using the id's of radio buttons but if I use the id's all the radio buttons are hidden and I am not able to see the radio buttons.

Is there any other way to do this without using the div tags?

Comment: Are you hiding them client-side or server-side?

Comment: welcome to SO. So where do you want to use your code. C# or Java-script. It seems that you are looking for javascript? The use clientId insted of id http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx

Comment: i am hiding them at client side.

Comment: i want to add my code in c#.

Comment: Please elaborate on why keeping the different variations within their own container that is then hidden/shown not desirable to you or whoever has tasked you with this?

Comment: Also, you say this is currently implemented client-side in JS but you want to instead now implement it in C# on the server-side. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think having each permutation in their own container that you hide/show is the better solution. I feel it makes your intent that much more clear and that in turns should make the code easier to maintain.

Comment: sorry, i didn't get that "permutation in their own container that you hide/show is the better solution.", can you please send me any sample code, you mean i need to keep this div tags in same place, is that is the solution for this problem.

Comment: That's not the only solution but personally I see no real issue with doing it that way. In my view it makes for cleaner code, assuming you don't have an outrageous number of permutations/variations of radio button combinations that is.